# Create Python list from raw lines in VSCode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Is there any nice way to create list from raw lines that i will copy inside VS Code?
e.g i have

```
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
```

and would like to reformat above to get

```
['Line 1',
'Line 2',
'Line 3']
```

Thanks

Comment: Answered by Ugur, https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=cshum.convert-newline-list-to-array

Answer (score 1):

Option 1.

You can use Ctrl+Shift+Up/Down Arrow Key to select multiple lines/columns. After you selected all the lines using this combination, you can put "'" at the start and end of all lines, then manually add "[" and "]" to the start and end.

Option 2.

You can check out regex usage for replace functionality to achieve similar.

Comment: Was doing Option 1 and im wondering if there is any built in feature

Comment: I found this site online, hope it helps :)
https://arraythis.com/

Comment: Also found this extension for VS Code, haven't tried it myself.
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=cshum.convert-newline-list-to-array